PHP openssl_private_encrypt have javascript analog
Need analog in javascript for openssl_private_encrypt php function.
I expect same output.
openssl-private-encrypt PHP reference
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-encrypt.php
<?php

openssl_private_encrypt(
    'RomaxaCoder',
    $partialSign,
    <<<PK
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
PK
);

var_dump(base64_encode($partialSign));


Output:
gBeCtvLsVAYI2ubm1Q2GHZoZdCYwGAIoDHxBf4K2O6tJ5FTojHS+n2OkMyNkLuAN93YlnPlefU4WV65OikhdJSghOsT4f8ZER01lweSvPNMgEdEABlHDDv7mWFwNkGi4qvSCgak+xP45G6zPUZJ3uHO5U4Ki1j3WQR0tyrRr5vI=

Need same result in javascript.

There are no standard VanilaJS analog, and I don't know how to make it.

index.js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const message = 'RomaxaCoder';

const privateKeyPem = `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`;

const privateKey = crypto.createPrivateKey({
  key: privateKeyPem,
  format: 'pem',
  type: 'pkcs1'
});
const encryptedBase64 = crypto.privateEncrypt(privateKey, Buffer.from(message, 'utf8')).toString('base64');

console.log(encryptedBase64);
console.log(encryptedBase64 === 'gBeCtvLsVAYI2ubm1Q2GHZoZdCYwGAIoDHxBf4K2O6tJ5FTojHS+n2OkMyNkLuAN93YlnPlefU4WV65OikhdJSghOsT4f8ZER01lweSvPNMgEdEABlHDDv7mWFwNkGi4qvSCgak+xP45G6zPUZJ3uHO5U4Ki1j3WQR0tyrRr5vI=');


Execution:
export OPENSSL_CONF=/dev/null && node index.js

Output:
gBeCtvLsVAYI2ubm1Q2GHZoZdCYwGAIoDHxBf4K2O6tJ5FTojHS+n2OkMyNkLuAN93YlnPlefU4WV65OikhdJSghOsT4f8ZER01lweSvPNMgEdEABlHDDv7mWFwNkGi4qvSCgak+xP45G6zPUZJ3uHO5U4Ki1j3WQR0tyrRr5vI=
true

